# Git ignore BOM (prevent git diff from showing byte order mark changes)

Tags: git, byte-order-mark, git-diff

I want `git diff` to not show [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) changes.
Such changes typically show up as `<feff>` in the diff:

```
-<feff>/*^M
+/*^M
```

How can I make `git diff` to behave this way?
Preferably with a command-line parameter.

`git --ignore-all-space` (aka `git -w`) does not do the trick.
I am on Mac OS X if that matters.

Comment: Would `git diff -w` (`--ignore-all-space`) work better?

Comment: @VonC: It does not do the trick unfortunately.

Comment: Ok. Then I don't know. Git doesn't seem to touch or ignore BOM (as seen in http://stackoverflow.com/a/6418611/6309)

Answer (score 7):

**Use Git Attributes filter**

One possible solution would be to create a BOM filter such as:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' "$1"
```

store it somewhere in your path (as i.e. `removebom`) and make it executable.

Then you need to configure the filter in Git by running:

```
$ git config diff.removebom.textconv removebom
```

and adding an attribute for files you are interested in (i.e. cpp) to your repository:

```
*.cpp diff=removebom
```

as a `.gitattributes` file.

More on the topic can be found on:

- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_diffing_binary_files
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381230/how-can-i-remove-the-bom-from-a-utf-8-file

**Or remove the BOM once for all**

... because, hopefully, the BOM may be removed once and for all in your project :)

Comment: I see that you might be using a UTF-16 BOM, then `'1s/^\xFE\xFF//'` might be the sed pattern you want... But in case of UTF-16, the BOM might be actually required and you are converting whole file to UTF-8; just beware of that.