# My git apply patch fails because the target file has UTF8 BOM - how do I fix it?

Tags: git, patch, byte-order-mark

As the title says, I am trying to apply a patch to a file and it fails because the file has the UTF8 BOM, but the patch does not mention it.

How can I resolve around it without removing the UTF8 BOM from the file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223985/git-ignore-bom-prevent-git-diff-from-showing-byte-order-mark-changes ?

Comment: I do not mind showing it. I need it in the context of applying patches. Specifically, I do not want the presence of it to fail the patch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to remove it, perhaps temporarily (i.e., remove it, apply patch, put it back).  Since `git apply` works by default on the work-tree contents, this should be easy enough and does not require making or deleting any commits.

Note that a UTF-8 BOM is technically useless, because UTF-8 has no byte-order issue in the first place.  (Some software might use it to imply that the file is UTF-8 encoded, though.)

Comment: I ended up doing what you suggest - remove, apply, put it back. It is not my business to remove the BOM, if it is there. It is frustrating, though, that git does not know to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by creating a whole-file patch (`git diff -B`). This patch could be applied. (Of course this works not for patches which you got from other places)