# designer.cs source control dilemma

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

I work on ios application using xamarin.ios.
The problem is that visual studio mac is stripping away Byte Order Mark `EF BB BF` sequence from `designer.cs` file. While visual studio windows always adds it.
When I commit `<controllerOrView>.designer.cs` with BOM on Windows, visual studio mac removes BOM and highlights file as changed `//Warning` line.
When I commit `<controllerOrView>.designer.cs` without BOM on Mac, visual studio windows hightlights it as changed.
How can I workaround this problem so that both visual studio Mac and visual studio windows get relaxed about Byte order mark and I don't have to filter files every time I want to commit?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223985/git-ignore-bom-prevent-git-diff-from-showing-byte-order-mark-changes

Comment: Perhaps add an editor config with the good encoding (and maybe install the editor config plug-in in all your editors) https://editorconfig.org/