# How to tell `git diff` to ignore changes in BOM or to treat them as whitespace changes?

Tags: git, encoding, utf-8, diff, byte-order-mark

I am using Git (version 2.20.1.vfs.1.1.104.g2ab7360) on Windows 10. I ran a command

```
git diff --ignore-all-space branch-1..branch-2
```

Unfortunately, there are many files that have changed their encoding from UTF-8 (BOM) to UTF-8 (No BOM) (or vice versa), so I see diffs like this:

[image]

How can I configure Git (or provide some command line flags) to ignore changes like this? We can assume that this sequence of bytes does not appear anywhere else in the source files.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223985/git-ignore-bom-prevent-git-diff-from-showing-byte-order-mark-changes ?

Comment: The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46151520/305118 in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223985/git-ignore-bom-prevent-git-diff-from-showing-byte-order-mark-changes does not actually directly answer either that question or mine. The questions ask how to configure `git diff` to ignore BOM rather than how automatically adjust BOM in files. And, apparently, that answer does not apply to Windows 10 that I explicitly mentioned in my question.