# Strange characters in git show command

Tags: git

I'm looking for the answer for strange character in git show like in the screen:

[image: git show command]

I have the same issue in git diff.

my .gitconfig file:

```
[user]
    name = user
    email = user@user.com
[difftool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = '' \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
[mergetool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = "'' "
    trustExitCode = true
[credential "https://...."]
    provider = generic
[core]
    editor = code --wait
[diff]
    tool = vscode
[difftool "vscode"]
    cmd = "code --wait --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE"
```

Edited:
I found the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36692549/12733938
but what strange it works for almost all files. Some still have same strange letter but for now is ok.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git ignore BOM (prevent git diff from showing byte order mark changes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223985/git-ignore-bom-prevent-git-diff-from-showing-byte-order-mark-changes)

Comment: Actually I think that's more likely related to your terminal setup - not being a windows user though I am not sure.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Any solution yet? I tried changing the encoding in VS Code to use UTF-8 with and without BOM, but no luck yet.

Answer (score 1):

The file you had committed in git is not UTF-8 encoded. It looks like UTF-16 LE BOM encoding which is typically in windows.
So you have to change the encoding to UTF-8 to fix your "strange character" problem.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Any solution yet? I tried changing the encoding in VS Code to use UTF-8 with and without BOM, but no luck yet.